GET RASTER LEAF AREA INDEX VEGETAION BY ERA5 IN R
I have a script to import raster by era5 data (format ".nc") from R. The problem is that when i export the raster i see that the value never change in many years. So i think my code is not enought to have the exact Raster.
So if someone have already did this before i need some help.
Thank you
#Read in the netCDF file contents
nc_data <- nc_open('data.nc')
# Save the print(nc) dump to a text file
{
  sink('data.txt')
  print(nc_data)
  sink()
}

lon <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "longitude")
lat <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "latitude", verbose = F)
t <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "time")
head(lon) # look at the first few entries in the longitude vector

lai_hv.array <- ncvar_get(nc_data, "lai_hv") # store the data in a 3-dimensional array
dim(lai_hv.array) 
#Other pertinent information about the (NDVI) variable: Lets’s see what fill value was used for missing data.
fillvalue <- ncatt_get(nc_data, "lai_hv", "_FillValue")
fillvalue

##Working with the data
lai_hv.array[lai_hv.array == fillvalue$value] <- NA
lai_hv.slice <- lai_hv.array[, , 1]

dim(lai_hv.slice)
r <- raster(t(lai_hv.slice), xmn=min(lon), xmx=max(lon), ymn=min(lat), ymx=max(lat), 
            crs=CRS("+proj=longlat +ellps=WGS84 +datum=WGS84 +no_defs+ towgs84=0,0,0"))

#Saving to a GeoTIFF
writeRaster(r,"output/lai_hv.tif", "GTiff", overwrite=TRUE)

